# ¿Como utilizar SweetAlert en archivo php?

Tags: php

Un archivo de php llamado archivo_destino1.php recibe y guarda en una base de datos los registros enviados desde un formulario tipo modal que esta en index.php, lo único que he podido hacer es redireccionar al header cuando ocurre un evento, lo que necesito es emplear alertas SweetAlert en este archivo php. Ya en el index.php agregue el siguiente enlace.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
```

y desde mi archivo sweetAlert.js estoy agregando con swal.fire todas las popiedades y me funciona enviando un mensaje de bienvenida. En el archivo_destino1.php no se como agregarlo. Este es el archivo php.

````
$oportunidad = 0;
//se establece una conexion a la base de datos
include 'conexion.php';
//si se han enviado datos
if (isset($_POST['datos_registrar_usuario']) and isset($_POST['datos_registrar_contraseña'])){
 $usuario=mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['datos_registrar_usuario']);
 $contraseña=password_hash($_POST['datos_registrar_contraseña'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
 $ingresar=mysqli_query($conexion,'insert into nombre_tabla(columna_usuario,columna_password,oportunidad) values
 ("'.$usuario.'","'.$contraseña.'","'.$oportunidad.'")') or die ('<p>Error al registrar</p><br>'.mysqli_error($conexion));
 //redirección
 header ('location: ./');
}//si no se enviaron datos
else{
 header ('location: ./');
}
?>```
````

Comment: Desde PHP debes generar código HTML + Javascript para que el navegador lo interprete y muestre la alerta.

Comment: Ya lo logre agregando: <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
    <script src="js/sweetAlert.js"></script>y consigo el alert cuando ingreso registros pero necesito que al dar clic en ok me envie al header y no lo hace me deja en el archivo registro.php